# Please give reference/guidance to make a web application for managing mails(like Microsoft Outlook ) in Asp.Net MVC(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

**Please give reference/guidance to make a web application for managing mails(like Microsoft Outlook)  in Asp.Net MVC(C#)**

We need to implement common functionalities from Microsoft Outlook

- sending and receiving email.
- Allows user to register mailbox,
  change  password, and modify user
  information.
- Allows administrator to create,
  delete, and disable user's mailbox
  and set mailbox size.
- Supports administrator sending email 
  to multiple users at a time.

Already i searched google for finding **mail server** to integrate in my application.I didn't get enough information.So Please give suggestion/reference

Comment: You'll want 2 Mail Clients (SMTP and (POP3 or IMAP)). And a few man-years of programming.

Comment: Any open source mail server exist for integrating in my web application

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read more about (Yahoo, Google, Hotmail, .. ) APIs . there is a clear steps to implement it using C# .